# MySQL fail to compare string - charset UTF8 and collation UTF8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I've this table

```
CREATE TABLE `login_user` (
  `id_user` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

and i've done this insert

```
insert into login_user (id_user,login) values (1,'uè')
```

Now this select

```
select * from login_user where login='uè'
```

return no values.

Why? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: `'ùè'` !== `'uè'` So it would appear to be working as expected

Comment: Specify needed collation in your condition explicitly.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/a6SJn5O4 Look current session settings.

Comment: if i use "select * from dettagli_utente_login dul where login = 'ùù' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci" it will find the "uu" login. Why?

Comment: To debug, please do `SELECT HEX(login) FROM login_user WHERE id_user = 1;`  Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored